# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getContacts'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Before posting the below, I have reviewed similar posts on stackoverflow but none resolved my issue.

I'm new to react and fetching data from firestore database. The below code works as required but getting this prompt within react

[image]

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {db} from '../firebase'



const ListRecord = () => {

    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getContacts()

    },[]);

        const getContacts = async() => {
            await db.collection('contacts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            let arr = []
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                arr.push({id: doc.id, value: doc.data()})
            });
                setDetails(arr);  
            });
            console.log(details);
            return details
        }
  

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>List Contact Details</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListRecord
```

As per other similar posts I tried moving the getContacts function inside useEffect body which make the prompt disapper but the getContacts function goes in a continuous loop.

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Move the `getContacts` declaration before the `useEffect()` block.

Comment: You mean like this:

 const getContacts = async() => {
        await db.collection('contacts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        let arr = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            arr.push({id: doc.id, value: doc.data()})
        });
            setDetails(arr);  
        });
        console.log(details);
    }
---------------------------------------------
    useEffect(() => {
        getContacts()

    },[]);

--------------- did not help ------

Comment: When you move the `getContacts()` function inside your `useEffect()` you do not have to add `details` to the dependency list; that is what is causing the infinite loop

Comment: @Jag99 remove `details` from the dependency array and `return details`

Comment: `details` in the dependency array is triggering the render looping. I don't see a dependency (other than the console log which won't work as you expect anyway). Just move the console log and `details` dependency into its own `useEffect` for logging state updates.

Comment: @Fraction : That fixed it. I have setDetails(arr), does that mean details has all the data?

Comment: @DrewReese : Thanks. How do i do that pls. I really like to know that im not continuously reading from firestore and I hit the read limit.

Comment: Sorry, are you asking how to do what I said you should do in my comment? Moving the console log and dependency for `details` to its own effect?

Comment: yes, after a component re-render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different potential solutions:

#### 1. Move getContacts() inside the useEffect() hook:

If you call getContacts() only once and only when the component mounts for the first time, this is probably the most logic solution.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getContacts = async () => {
    await db.collection('contacts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      let arr = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        arr.push({
          id: doc.id,
          value: doc.data()
        })
      });
      setDetails(arr);
    });
    //console.log(details);
    //return details // why are you returning details?
  }
  
  getContacts()
}, [setDetails]); // setDetails() is granted to never change therefore the hook will never re-run
```

or, of course, you can use an IIFE:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async function() {
    // ... same body as getContacts 
  })()
}, [setDetails])
```

#### 2. Use a useCallback() hook:

This is something you might want to do if `getContacts()` is called more than once (for example, when the component mounts *and* every time some prop changes or when you click on some button)

```js
const getContacts = useCallback(async () => {
  await db.collection('contacts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    let arr = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        id: doc.id,
        value: doc.data()
      })
    });
    setDetails(arr);
  });
  //console.log(details);
  //return details // why are you returning details?
}, [setDetail]); // setDetails() is granted to never change therefore getContacts() will never be re-created

useEffect(() => {
  getContacts()
}, [getContacts]); // as getContacts() never changes, this will run only once
```

#### 3. Move getContacts() out of the component and make it an independent function:

This can make sense if you want to reuse the same logic into other components:

```js
// getContacts.js file
// OR this code could be in the ListRecord.js file but **outside** the component,
// although, in this case, solutions (1) or (2) would make more sense
import { db } from 'path/to/firebase'

export async function getContacts() {
  await db.collection('contacts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    let arr = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        id: doc.id,
        value: doc.data()
      })
    });
    return arr; // this time you HAVE TO return arr
  });
}

// ListRecord.js file
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getContacts } from 'path/to/getContacts.js';

const ListRecord = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const arr = await getContacts();
    if (arr && arr.length > 0) setDetails(arr);
  }, [setDetails]);
  
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to comment out that too; I'll do it immediately. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Thanks @secan, this is really helpful. Option 1 works for me. 
final query
: how do i render the data from details using map.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your doubt is about using `map()`; you use it as you would do for any array; for example `details.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.value}</div>)`. Just remember to add the `key` attribute when you render elements of an array via a loop; then it is no different from rendering any other element.

Comment: Here you can see a simplified example of the entire component: https://jsfiddle.net/0651odfb/2/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at how `useEffect` and its dependency list works in the official document.

In short, do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getContacts()
}, [getContacts]);
```

This means when `getContacts` changes, the `useEffect` will be re-run.

Comment: yes, i did try that. As shared others have had the same issue and i tried all the recommendations before posting

Comment: Unless you memoize `getContacts` callback, this will trigger render looping as well since `getContacts` is redeclared each render cycle. The linter will attempt to warn you about this.